# Elasticserch 2.3.5 encrypting string values

Tags: elasticsearch

I just built Cluster with Elasticsearch 2.3.5, and I have loaded data using the elasticsearch-spark(elasticsearch-hadoop 2.3.4) connector. Everything looks good except strings get encrypted as below...

```
    "changeaudioodstreams": "LTguMw==",
    "enm": "QW50aWRvdGU=",
    "pid": 33,
    "uid": 33,
    "upid": 33,
    "pnm": "VHJhdmlzIFNjb3R0",
    "upnm": "VHJhdmlzIFNjb3R0",
    "rd": "MjAxNS0wNy0zMA==",
    "weekid": 201601
```

Is there any property to disable this?

Comment: I have corrected a typo in your question title, and tightened up the wording in the question. Feel free to [edit] your question further to make more improvements - editing is encouraged on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I don't think elasticsearch is able to actually do anything to your document values. Also, there's no such thing as an encryption feature in Elasticsearch. So, I think you are probably looking at the wrong part of your architecture for solving this.

Comment: Thanks Vince Bowdren and Jilles. I have manually created an index in ES and added data through curl command. it does not encrypt data.

I am using spark job to load data using hadoop elasticsearch connector(elasticsearch-hadoop-2.3.4.jar),Not sure how data getting encrypted, any help Pl?

I had used earlier elasticsearch-hadoop-2.1.0.jar with Elasticsearch 1.7 and see no issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setting below property in spark code fixed the issue

```
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.parquet.binaryAsString", "true");
```